# Large amount of pages scraping trouble

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, file-get-contents

I'm trying to obtain data from a two-level website. Level one contains a few thousands of links to the level two. I found it works just when I let to be scraped one top level page at a time only. When I try to scrape more of them at once, I receive an error message after about 40 min of run.
I tried both `file_get_contents ()` and `curl_exec ()` functions, but neither of them was able to handle the task. The later method once wasn't even able to complete the one task. It seems the script is causing memory overflow. Is there any better way to do this job?

Comment: Have you tried just using `curl` at the command-line and doing your parsing using a bash script?

Comment: No, I have not. But I'd prefer doing it using PHP only.

Comment: What is the error you are getting after 40 minutes?

Comment: Error 500 Internal server error

Answer (score 1):

A 500 Internal server error means that it's a server problem, not a client problem. It may even be a deliberate anti-robot server policy to prevent exactly this kind of scraping, although the fact that it works fine for 40 minutes makes it seem like it's more likely just a server capacity problem on a poorly-managed server. Slowing down the rate of requests will be the solution if that's the case.